# Mass storage device fails to mount

Tags: usb-drive, removable-storage

I bought a device that apparently is meant to be used as mass storage.

When plugging it on my linux machine, it doesn't mount and I get those errors:

```
[ 2603.332019] usb 2-5: new full-speed USB device number 10 using ohci-pci
[ 2603.544655] usb 2-5: New USB device found, idVendor=1b3f, idProduct=30fe
[ 2603.544660] usb 2-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 2603.544662] usb 2-5: Product: USBDEVICE
[ 2603.544664] usb 2-5: Manufacturer: GENERALPLUS 
[ 2603.547707] usb-storage 2-5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2603.547911] scsi host12: usb-storage 2-5:1.0
[ 2604.556661] scsi 12:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generalp lus SD Device V2 .0.0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 2604.557109] sd 12:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg9 type 0
[ 2604.567644] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdi] 32768 512-byte logical blocks: (16.8 MB/16.0 MiB)
[ 2604.574641] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdi] Write Protect is off
[ 2604.574645] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdi] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[ 2604.581641] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdi] No Caching mode page found
[ 2604.581644] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdi] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2604.631654]  sdi:
[ 2604.679644] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdi] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 2604.700645] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdi] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 2604.700660] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdi] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 2604.700667] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdi] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[ 2604.700673] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdi] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 7f 80 00 00 08 00
[ 2604.700677] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdi, sector 32640
[ 2604.717636] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdi] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 2604.717645] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdi] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 2604.717649] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdi] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[ 2604.717653] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdi] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 7f 80 00 00 08 00
[ 2604.717658] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdi, sector 32640
[ 2604.717661] Buffer I/O error on dev sdi, logical block 4080, async page read
```

I'm using a recent kernel:

```
Linux 4.5.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.5.1-1~bpo8+1 (2016-04-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have access to a Windows laptop. On this machine, I can mount the device and load a file.

From linux, using `gnome-disk-utility`, I see the device but formatting fails.

On Windows, I can format the device as FAT with default options, but even then, it is still unreadable from my linux machine.

The device is a wireless doorbell. The USB interface allows the user to load .mp3 files to use as custom ring melodies:

- [fr] http://www.leroymerlin.fr/v3/p/produits/carillon-sans-fil-mp3-flash-evology-noir-et-blanc-e1401169056
- [pl] http://www.leroymerlin.pl/zabezpieczenie-domu/dzwonki-gongi-domofony/dzwonki-i-gongi-bezprzewodowe/dzwonek-bezprzewodowy-c-303-evology,p385866,l1127.html

#### Edit: attempts on another computer

I was suggested it may be a hardware compatibility issue, so I'm checking on other computers.

kernel:

```
Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2 (2016-04-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

log:

```
[  211.284009] usb 1-3.4: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  211.395905] usb 1-3.4: New USB device found, idVendor=1b3f, idProduct=30fe
[  211.395908] usb 1-3.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  211.395910] usb 1-3.4: Product: USBDEVICE
[  211.395911] usb 1-3.4: Manufacturer: GENERALPLUS 
[  211.436522] usb-storage 1-3.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  211.436608] scsi10 : usb-storage 1-3.4:1.0
[  211.436697] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  212.439737] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generalp lus SD Device V2 .0.0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  212.440255] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  212.445342] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] 32768 512-byte logical blocks: (16.7 MB/16.0 MiB)
[  212.448363] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  212.448367] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[  212.451971] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  212.451976] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  212.476600]  sdb:
[  212.499568] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  212.508188] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Device not ready
[  212.508191] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[  212.508192] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  212.508194] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[  212.508195] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  212.508198] Info fld=0x0
[  212.508199] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[  212.508202] Add. Sense: Medium not present
[  212.508204] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[  212.508205] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 7f 80 00 00 08 00
[  212.508211] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 32640
[  212.508214] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 4080
[  212.515687] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Device not ready
[  212.515689] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[  212.515691] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  212.515692] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[  212.515693] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  212.515695] Info fld=0x0
[  212.515697] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[  212.515699] Add. Sense: Medium not present
[  212.515700] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[  212.515701] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 7f 80 00 00 08 00
[  212.515706] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 32640
[  212.515708] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 4080
```

#### Edit 2: attempts on yet another computer (old Dell latitude)

kernel:

```
Linux 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.54-2 i686 GNU/Linux
```

log:

```
[  352.816123] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
[  352.988140] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1b3f, idProduct=30fe
[  352.988152] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  352.988160] usb 1-1: Product: USBDEVICE
[  352.988166] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: GENERALPLUS 
[  353.129013] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[  353.130932] scsi2 : usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[  353.131211] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  353.131219] USB Mass Storage support registered.
[  354.133013] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generalp lus SD Device V2 .0.0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  354.138372] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  354.142948] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 32768 512-byte logical blocks: (16.7 MB/16.0 MiB)
[  354.147962] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  354.147975] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[  354.151952] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  354.151966] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  354.172966] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  354.172979] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  354.180090]  sdb:
[  354.207968] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  354.207982] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  354.207992] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  354.214947] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Device not ready
[  354.214956] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  354.214966] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  354.214978] Info fld=0x0
[  354.214983] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: Medium not present
[  354.214996] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 7f 80 00 00 08 00
[  354.215021] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 32640
[  354.215033] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 4080
[  354.222946] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Device not ready
[  354.222956] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  354.222966] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  354.222977] Info fld=0x0
[  354.222982] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: Medium not present
[  354.222995] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 7f 80 00 00 08 00
[  354.223019] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 32640
[  354.223031] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 4080
[  354.229881] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Device not ready
[  354.229891] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  354.229901] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  354.229913] Info fld=0x0
[  354.229918] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: Medium not present
[  354.229932] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 7f f0 00 00 08 00
[  354.229955] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 32752
[  354.229966] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 4094
[  354.237954] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Device not ready
[  354.237964] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  354.237975] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  354.237986] Info fld=0x0
[  354.237991] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: Medium not present
[  354.238004] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 7f f0 00 00 08 00
[  354.238027] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 32752
[  354.238039] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 4094
[  354.259868] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Device not ready
[  354.259878] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  354.259888] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  354.259899] Info fld=0x0
[  354.259905] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: Medium not present
[  354.259918] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 7f f8 00 00 01 00
[  354.259941] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 32760
[  354.259952] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 4095
[  354.267948] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Device not ready
[  354.267960] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  354.267970] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  354.267981] Info fld=0x0
[  354.267987] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: Medium not present
[  354.268000] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 7f f8 00 00 01 00
[  354.268057] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 32760
[  354.268068] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 4095
[  354.276948] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Device not ready
[  354.276958] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  354.276968] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  354.276981] Info fld=0x0
[  354.276986] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: Medium not present
[  354.277001] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 7f f8 00 00 01 00
[  354.277025] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 32760
[  354.277036] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 4095
[  354.283870] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Device not ready
[  354.283880] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  354.283890] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  354.283902] Info fld=0x0
[  354.283907] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: Medium not present
[  354.283921] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 7f f8 00 00 01 00
[  354.283944] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 32760
[  354.283955] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 4095
[  354.291935] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Device not ready
[  354.291946] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  354.291955] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  354.291967] Info fld=0x0
[  354.291972] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: Medium not present
[  354.291985] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 7f f8 00 00 01 00
[  354.292040] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 32760
[  354.292052] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 4095
[  354.298935] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Device not ready
[  354.298945] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  354.298955] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  354.298967] Info fld=0x0
[  354.298972] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: Medium not present
[  354.298985] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 7f f8 00 00 01 00
[  354.299008] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 32760
[  354.299018] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 4095
[  354.305937] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Device not ready
[  354.305947] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  354.305956] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  354.305968] Info fld=0x0
[  354.305973] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: Medium not present
[  354.305986] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 7f f8 00 00 01 00
[  354.306009] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 32760
[  354.313934] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Device not ready
[  354.313943] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  354.313953] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  354.313964] Info fld=0x0
[  354.313969] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: Medium not present
[  354.313982] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 7f c0 00 00 08 00
[  354.314005] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 32704
[  354.320935] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Device not ready
[  354.320945] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  354.320954] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  354.320966] Info fld=0x0
[  354.320971] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: Medium not present
[  354.320984] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 7f f0 00 00 08 00
[  354.321007] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 32752
[  354.328938] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Device not ready
[  354.328948] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  354.328958] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  354.328969] Info fld=0x0
[  354.328974] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: Medium not present
[  354.328988] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 7f f8 00 00 01 00
[  354.329011] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 32760
[  354.335860] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Device not ready
[  354.335870] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  354.335880] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  354.335892] Info fld=0x0
[  354.335897] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: Medium not present
[  354.335910] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 7f f8 00 00 01 00
[  354.335934] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 32760
[  354.343928] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Device not ready
[  354.343938] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  354.343948] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  354.343959] Info fld=0x0
[  354.343965] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: Medium not present
[  354.343978] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 7f f8 00 00 01 00
[  354.344001] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 32760
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82845 845 [Brookdale] Chipset Host Bridge (rev 04)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82845 845 [Brookdale] Chipset AGP Bridge (rev 04)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801CA/CAM USB Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 42)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801CAM ISA Bridge (LPC) (rev 02)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801CAM IDE U100 Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.5 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801CA/CAM AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.6 Modem: Intel Corporation 82801CA/CAM AC'97 Modem Controller (rev 02)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV200 [Mobility Radeon 7500]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: 3Com Corporation 3c905C-TX/TX-M [Tornado] (rev 78)
02:01.0 CardBus bridge: Texas Instruments PCI1420 PC card Cardbus Controller
02:01.1 CardBus bridge: Texas Instruments PCI1420 PC card Cardbus Controller
```

Comment: This looks like an error I saw when attaching a USB3 disk to a USB2 interface a while ago. Can you try booting a Live CD on your Windows laptop to rule out hardware incompatibility?

Comment: I was suggested the same hardware compatibility issue possibility. Hence my attempts on other computers at home. Unfortunately, all of them are pretty old (but run Linux like a charm...). Thanks for confirming this is a good lead. I'll try to test on Linux on a recent machine like you suggest.